# Flex staked Y-Axis

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I'm trying to make chart which is combination of bar and line chart using Flex Charting API .
Here x axis would be common and y axis would be different. Please not that y axis got different range of value one is %  and other is amount. Any one got idea how to make this chart.  Here line chart would be staked  on top of bar chart . The line chart and never over laid or drawn on top of bar chart. Please help... please..

Thanks ,
James

Comment: Stacked? So that the whole line chart, including its axis, is complete above the other one?

Answer (score 1):

Start from the CartesianChart. Add LineSeries and BarSeries (or maybe you mean ColumnSeries).

This example is close:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_12.html

--edit

For the chart stacking dilemma: let the charts be separate with their own axes. Just hide the horizontal axis from the top chart.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer. In the livedocs example which you mentioned above the Y axis is on right and line chart drawn on top of bar chart. My requirement is to keep the second y axis on the top of the first y axis the second y axis values would be different from first axis(say first  is % and second is amount). Here the x axis would be same. The second graph plotted based on the values of second y axis and the common x axis, let me know  if that make sense. Any idea please. Thanks James

Comment: I tried the removing x axis from the top graph, there is a problem with that approach the data points in lower graph x axis and upper graph x axis is not aligned so the final result would be in line graph axis point and bar chart x axis points would not be same.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem there. How about this: give id to bottom graph x axis and try to use it as top graph's x axis by binding.